# ¿Se puede realmente cambiar el directorio de descarga predeterminado para una sesión de Chrome ya abierta usando Selenium en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, depuración, descarga

Estoy tratando de descargar unos archivos zippeados de [esta página](https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/futures/um/daily/markPriceKlines/ADAUSDT/1h/) a una ruta específica en  para una sesión de Chrome ya abierta usando el siguiente código:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222") #this allows bulk-dozer to take control of your Chrome Browser in DevTools mode.
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Downloads\Binance futures data\ADAUSDT-Mark_Prices_Klines_1h_Timeframe"}) #set the path to save the desired zipped data 
s = Service(r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe') #Use the chrome driver located at the corresponding path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) #execute the chromedriver.exe with the previous conditions

#Why using MarkPrices: https://support.btse.com/en/support/solutions/articles/43000557589-index-price-and-mark-price#:~:text=Index%20Price%20is%20an%20important,of%20cryptocurrencies%20on%20major%20exchanges.&text=Mark%20Price%20is%20the%20price,be%20fair%20and%20manipulation%20resistant.

if driver.current_url == 'https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/futures/um/daily/markPriceKlines/ADAUSDT/1h/' :   
    number = 2 #initialize an int variable to 2 because the desired web elements in this page starts from 2
    counter = 0
    the_dictionary_links = {}
    while number <= np.size(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="listing"]/tr')): #iterate over the tbody array
        data_file_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="listing"]/tr[{number}]/td[1]/a').text
        if data_file_name.endswith('CHECKSUM') == False:
            the_dictionary_links[data_file_name] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="listing"]/tr[{number}]/td[1]/a').get_attribute('href')
            print(f'Saving {data_file_name} and its link for later use')
            counter += 1            
        number += 1
    print(counter)
    i = 0
    o = 0
    for i,o in the_dictionary_links.items():
        driver.get(o)
        print(f'Downloading {i}')
        time.sleep(1.8)
```

Y desafortunadamente no funciona, este código arroja el siguiente error:

> **InvalidArgumentException:** invalid argument: cannot parse capability:
> goog:chromeOptions from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option:
> prefs

Entonces, me gustaría saber ¿qué pudo haber salido mal? Hice el programa de arriba teniendo en cuenta esta [otra solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70158335/how-to-download-files-in-customized-location-using-selenium-chromedriver-and-chr/70159116#70159116) pero este último parece que sólo funciona en una nueva sesión de Chrome, y necesito que el directorio de descargas predeterminado sea modificable para una sesión ya abierta. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que sigue siendo un navegador normal solo que puede controlarse por código, podrías intentar cambiarlo entrando a los ajustes. También podrías configurarlo para que consulte cada vez dónde guardar las descargas https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-handle-custom-download-location-in-selenium-chrome-78daaacd79ab . Otra cosa que podrías intentar es hacer las descargas por fuera del navegador. Con las funciones de red de Python o alguna librería.

Comment: Pues, de hecho yo usé una versión anterior a este programa en la que antes de ejecutarlo habia manualmente establecido la ruta del directorio de descargas predeterminado, y funcionó como esperaba, pero sí quisiera automatizarlo más sí es posible, por cierto ¿a qué te refieres con hacer las descargas por fuera del navegador usando funciones de red de Python? @Mateo

Comment: Por ejemplo urlretrieve. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776/13419694